# DB2 NVL with empty string

Tags: sql, db2

As in DB2, empty string and null are unlike in Oracle. Is there any method to realize NVL but with empty string？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine it with [`NULLIF`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_nullif.html):

> The NULLIF function returns the null value if the two arguments are equal; otherwise, it returns the value of the first argument.

```
SELECT NVL(NULLIF(col, ''),'replacement')
```

Comment: I also came up with this solution and it should be the simplest one. Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
case when mycol = '' then 'some value' else mycol end
```

If you want to handle `null` values as well:

```
case when mycol = '' 
       or mycol is null 
    then 'some value' 
    else mycol 
end
```